# Is it possible to install Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 11 without an internet connection?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

My company is not using the internet on our work -- just the network within the company. But they want me to install Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL in my PC without an internet connection.

I only have the Linux distribution package. I already tried the `Add-AppxPackage` command. But when I tried to execute `wsl -l`, it says there is no Linux distro installed.

Comment: Don't know if MS provides such and option. You can check the manual (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) or ask the companies' IT for help.

Answer (score 1):

> I only have the Linux distribution package. I already tried the `Add-AppxPackage` command

So it sounds like you are making good progress.  You actually seem to have "installed" WSL at this point.  That involves three items itself:

- [Enabling the WSL feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-1---enable-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux) in Windows 11 (which is already installed with Windows)
- [Enabling the Virtual Machine Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-3---enable-virtual-machine-feature), which enables WSL2, and is also installed with Windows 11 itself.
- Downloading and [installing the Linux kernel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package), which it does sound like you've done.  I'm assuming that this is what you mean by *"Linux Distribution Package"*, but that's a little confusing since you mention installing it with the `Add-AppxPackage` command, which you usually wouldn't do.  Please do confirm that you've completed this step, though.
- [Setting WSL2 to be the default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-5---set-wsl-2-as-your-default-version) version.

You can check these steps with `wsl --status`.  You should at least see a kernel version and default WSL2 version.

You might also consider installing the latest Preview (or even Pre-release) of WSL from the [Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases) while you are at this stage.

To install Ubuntu 20.04 into WSL2 without an internet connection, download *"Ubuntu 20.04"* from [this Microsoft Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#downloading-distributions) and install it with the `Add-AppxPackage` as *your regular user*, (not an Administrator).

If you've done this already, you may have done it as Administrator, but I'm not sure.

If it still doesn't work as your regular user, let me know -- There are additional alternatives, but that *should* be working.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried these steps. I installed it as a regular user. But still whenever I tried to open ubuntu.exe, there is a timeout error. After the step Add-AppxPackage, is it correct that I should execute the ubuntu.exe?